# Issue with package : NameError: name 'warn' is not defined

Tags: python, package

I am trying to use this package to get data from eurostat : https://pypi.org/project/eurostat/#description

The interesting part for me is : "Check what datasets are available via SDMX"

I have just try one of their example :

```
avail_sdmx_df = eurostat.get_avail_sdmx_df()
avail_sdmx_df
```

And I have the issue :

```
NameError: name 'warn' is not defined
```

Exactly the same issue when I am testing other funtion:

```
dims = eurostat.get_sdmx_dims('DS-066341')
dims
```

Finally, I go a little into the code of the app, and in the file
\venv\lib\site-packages\pandasdmx\message.py there is so import like :

```
from warnings import warn
```

So it is just that? An error from the team in the code then I cannot use this package?
Or there is some solution (or maybe something I am doing wrong on my side)

Thanks

EDIT : I am stupid, the files come from pandasdmw package, so not directly link to eurostat package, right?

Answer (score 1):

You need to Import warnings package/library.

Check below

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```